# Cypher -Neo4j Set the node attribute value in Variable length paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I am new to neo4j , I have the following situation

```
match (c:customer{id:'12345'})-[r:buys]->(b:item)
with b,b.total as z
match (b)-[same:*1..z)]->(d)
return d
```

In the above query z is an integer,But the above query is not working,

I would appreciate all helps and suggestions, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variable for path lengths. A workaround for that would be:

```
match (c:customer{id:'12345'})-[r:buys]->(b:item)
with b,b.total as z
match p=(b)-[same:*1..9999)]->(d)
where length(p)=z 
return d
```

Replace the 9999 by a kind of global upper limit suitable for your use case. Be warned, this might be pretty inefficient. In this case it might be better to send 2 Cypher statements:

```
match (c:customer{id:'12345'})-[r:buys]->(b:item) return id(b), b.total as z
```

For the second query insert the value for z via string concatenation:

```
match (b)-[same:*1..<z>)]->(d) return d
```